# Change Windows PIN requirements in Intune for an Azure AD-joined PC

Tags: windows, entra-id, password-management, microsoft-intune

I am the part-time admin of a small nonprofit, with a Microsoft 365 Business Premium subscription. I have been searching through admin.microsoft.com and portal.azure.com, but can't seem to find the settings for:

- Allowing licensed Business Premium users to have an alphanumeric PIN (as opposed to just numeric) with their Azure AD-linked accounts
- Disabling PIN change requirements

(This is on an Azure AD-joined Windows 11 Pro PC.)

Comment: Are these managed with Intune/MDM?

Comment: @GregAskew No, the PC/account is not.

Comment: @GregAskew I was wrong - yes, they are managed by Intune - can I get to the correct settings now?

Answer (score 1):

In brief, you'll need to go to the Microsoft Endpoint Manager admin center at https://endpoint.microsoft.com/ and log in with an Intune administrator role.

- Go to Devices, Compliance Policies
- Click Create policy
- Choose the relevant platform ("Windows 10 and later") and click create
- Type in a name and description, click next
- Expand the System Security node of the policy
- Configure your desired PIN settings
- Complete the rest of the policy's settings for non-compliance actions and assignments to the proper device groups (test first!)
- Proceed through the wizard to Review + create, and save.